# How to add month and year in infopath Designer 2013?

Tags: infopath, infopath2010

My form Design

```
 Year         : 1        (Text Box)

 Start Date   : 01/2014  (Text Box)

 End Date     : 01/2015  (Text Box)
```

If user enter 1 in year text box  it's equal to 12 months (if 2 means 24 months)

Start Date is enter by user manually like 01/2014 (same like 02/2015 , 01/2016 ...)

End date is automatically calculated and value come like above sample.

year =1
Start Date   : 01/2014
End Date     : 01/2015

How to do this....

Answer (score 0):

I find out  solution for my problem.

I apply start Date and End Date Format = string

And apply following substring formula

Field : End Date

Value :

```
concat(substring-before(start Date, "/"), "/", substring-after(start Date, "/") + Year)
```

Apply this formula to Start Date

Comment: Make sure your Year text box is not accepting "." (because if accept 1.5 how it will add)

Comment: Ok Thank you SAT. I apply your method.

Comment: if there is any other method available for my requirement